# Can one bundle multiple Eclipse plugins in one project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing several little plugins for Eclipse. Each one having it's own name, view and icon.

I am now having them in separate projects and as I am reviewing my code, package structure etc. I asked myself: Is it possible to bundle them all in one project called (for example) Plugins or does each one has to have a separate project because of plugin.xml, manifest.mf etc.

I know, each plugin needs to have these files, but can there be more then one plugin in them?

Comment: You can have one (general) project with nested plug-in projects in PDE.

Comment: Do you see any advantages with only having a single project or are you trying to solve some problem? I think having all code in the same project will likely lead to issues. For example the IDE wouldn't prevent you from using classes of the other plugins at compile time that are not in exported packages and fail loading those classes at runtime. Many parts of PDE will likely fail to handle multi-plugin projects correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. We settled with multiple projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it is possible using bnd-tools way of plugin creation but not via PDE. But if you want you can migrate PDE plugins to bnd. If you are interested check http://bndtools.org/